# Running short of something

Tags: phrase-usage

The phrase running short of something means when you don't have enough of something, but I want to mention how much of something I am running short of for example I want to buy a pair of shoes the price was around 100$ but I found out that I had only 90$ so needed 10$ now how would I describe it using running short of?
"I am running short by 10$ or
"I am running short of 10$.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a duplicate. If you are _running_  short of something you use regularly, your supplies of it are getting low; we wouldn't use the phrase to describe lacking a certain sum of money.

Comment: What @Kate said. You wouldn't normally *be **running** short of/by $10* - you'd just ***be** $10 short*.